# Expectation and Variance of a sum of Independent random variables

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, expected-value, variance

If I have n independent random variables, such that $S=p_1X_1+p_2X_2+p_3X_3+\cdots+p_nX_n$, where $\sum_{i=1}^np_i=1$. To find the expectation and variance of S, given $\mu_i=E(x_i)$, $\sigma_i=V(x_i)$,

$E(x)=\sum_{i=1}^np_i\mu_i$ and $V(x)=\sum_{i=1}^np_iE(x_i^2)-\sum_{i=1}^np_iE(x_i)^2=\sum_{i=i}^np_i\sigma_i^2$.

There is no need to use the law of total expectation/variance. Am I on the right track? Thank you!

Comment: Your definition of variance is wrong. It should be $\sum_{i=1}^n p_i^2 \sigma_i^2$. The way you are describing your reasoning makes me think that you just review these topics a little more to make sure you are comfortable in the analysis.

Comment: @Gregory Actually this is for some other class, but I am taking an analysis class now. I know I must be missing something here since I understand that $V(ax+b)=a^2V(x)$ by $V(ax+b)=a^2E((x-\mu)^2)$. I suppose there is somethign wrong in my summation. Do you mind give me another hint? Thank you!

Comment: Your expression for $V(X)$ is wrong, and I think it's because you're mixing up the $p_i$ that are your own coefficients with the $p_i$ that represent the probabilities in the expression.

Comment: @ConMan Right, now I see the problem. Thank you! $V(x)=\sum_{i=1}^nE((p_ix_i)^2)-\sum_{i=1}^n[p_iE(x_i)]^2=\sum_{i=1}^np_i^2E(x_i^2)-\sum_{i=1}^np_i^2E(x_i)^2=\sum_{i=i}^np_i^2\sigma_i^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close.

For linear combinations of independent random variables $X_i$ with means $\mu_i$ and variances $\sigma^2_i$ we do the following:

If
$$S_n = \sum_1^n p_iX_i$$

Then

$$E[S_n]= \sum_1^n p_i\mu_i,\;\; V[S_n] = \sum_1^n p_i^2\sigma_i^2$$

Answer (score 1):

Since it seems that you have some doubts about the underlying concepts, let me add some details to Annika's answer.

Let $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n p_i X_i$. Then, since expectation is a linear operator
$$
E[S_n] = E\biggl[\sum_{i=1}^n p_i X_i\biggr]=\sum_{i=1}^n p_i E\bigl[X_i\bigr]=\sum_{i=1}^n p_i \mu_i.
$$
Note that this is always true, it doesn't matter whether the $X_i$ are independent or not.

Now, as for the variance:
\begin{align*}
V[S_n] &= E\Bigl[\bigl(S_n - E[S_n]\bigr)^2\Bigr] \\
&= E\Bigl[\bigl(\sum_{i=1}^n p_i X_i - \sum_{i=1}^n p_i \mu_i\bigr)^2\Bigr] &&\text{[by our previous result]}\\
&= E\Bigl[\bigl(\sum_{i=1}^n p_i (X_i - \mu_i)\bigr)^2\Bigr] \\
&= E\Bigl[\bigl(\sum_{i=1}^n p_i (X_i - \mu_i)\bigr)\bigl(\sum_{j=1}^n p_j (X_j - \mu_j)\bigr)\Bigr] \\
&= E\Bigl[\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n p_i p_j (X_i - \mu_i)(X_j - \mu_j)\Bigr] \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n p_i p_j E\Bigl[(X_i - \mu_i)(X_j - \mu_j)\Bigr] &&\text{[by the linearity of $E$]}.
\end{align*}

At this point we have two different cases. If $i=j$, then
$$
E\Bigl[(X_i - \mu_i)(X_i - \mu_i)\Bigr] = E\Bigl[(X_i - \mu_i)^2\Bigr]=V(X_i)=\sigma_i^2.
$$
In the second case, when $i\ne j$, we finally take advantage of the fact that the $X_i$ are independent to one another - indeed, this allows us to write the expectation of the product as the product of the expectations:
\begin{multline}
E\Bigl[(X_i - \mu_i)(X_j - \mu_j)\Bigr] = E[X_i - \mu_i]E[X_j - \mu_j] \\
= \bigl(E[X_i] - \mu_i\bigr)\bigl(E[X_j] - \mu_j\bigr) = (\mu_i - \mu_i)(\mu_j - \mu_j)=0.
\end{multline}

Wrapping up
\begin{align*}
V[S_n] &= \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n p_i p_j E\Bigl[(X_i - \mu_i)(X_j - \mu_j)\Bigr] \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n p_i^2 E\Bigl[(X_i - \mu_i)^2\Bigr] + \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{\substack{j=1 \\ j\ne i}}^n p_i p_j E\Bigl[(X_i - \mu_i)(X_j - \mu_j)\Bigr] \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n p_i^2\sigma_i^2 + \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{\substack{j=1 \\ j\ne i}}^n p_i p_j \cdot 0 \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n p_i^2\sigma_i^2.
\end{align*}

Comment: +1 nice explanation!

Comment: This is a really nice explanation, thank you!